# Error on array validation in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to validate array value in laravel 5.4. Here is my code . It show me error.
It shows

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'card_no.0' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cards` where
>   `card_no`.`0` = 2005)"

When I tried to insert duplicate 2005. Is it possible to show which value is incorrect ? Thanks in advance.

**blade**

```
name="card_no[]"
```

**controller function**

```
public function store_card(Request $request)
{
   $this-> validate(request(),[ 
    "card_no.*" => 'required|max:255|unique:cards', 
    ]);


    $ent_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $card_no = $request->card_no;


    foreach($card_no as $value){ 
        $card = new card() ;
        $card->card_no = $value;
        $card->ent_date = $ent_date;
        $card->flag = '1';
        $card->save();
                  }

    return redirect('card');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to provide a column name for the unique rule and if you don't, Laravel will add the input name by itself. 
You can refer to the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique).
To fix this issue change the rule to the following instead:

`"card_no.*" => 'required|max:255|unique:cards,card_no'`

Comment: it works but doesn't show message. My view code @if($errors->has('card_no'))  <p> wrong </p> @endif

Comment: Oh I fixed that @if($errors->has('card_no.*'))
Thanks a lot.

Comment: my second part was, Is it possible to show which value is incorrect ?

Comment: yes, the  *  in `card_no.*`  should give you the index.

Comment: <strong style="color:red;">Duplicate card number is not allowed {{ $errors->first('card_no.*') }}</strong>